# Print all nodes in a tree method

Tags: java, debugging, recursion

I am making a recursive method for a tree that adds all nodes to an array list `names`. This method is not able to add the leaf nodes (nodes that have no children) to the arraylist `names`.

It only adds the root and the immediate children of the root to the array-list. I need to know what's wrong in order to solve other recursive problems.

```
private ArrayList<TreeNode> names = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<TreeNode> getAllNodes(){

    //BASIS CASES:
    names.add(this);

    if(isLeaf()){
        names.add(this);
        return names;
    }

    //RECURSIVE CASES:
    for(TreeNode child : children){
        child.getAllNodes();
        names.add(child);

    }

    return names;
}
```

Other code:

```
 //prints the nodes out
 ArrayList<TreeNode> theNodes = treeRoot.getAllNodes();
                System.out.println("");
                for (TreeNode n : theNodes) System.out.print(n.getLabel() + " ");
                repaintCanvas(canvas);

//hard coded nodes
treeRoot = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.MALE, "John", null);
        itemsToDraw.add(treeRoot);

        TreeNode Louis = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.MALE, "Louis", treeRoot);
        TreeNode Sue = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.FEMALE, "Sue", treeRoot);
        TreeNode Anne = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.FEMALE, "Anne", Sue);
        TreeNode Sam = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.MALE, "Sam", Sue);
        TreeNode Anne2 = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.FEMALE, "Anne", Sam);
        TreeNode Ed = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.MALE, "Ed", Louis);
        TreeNode Frank = new TreeNode(TreeNode.Gender.MALE, "Frank", Louis);
```

Output:

> John Louis Sue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the basic problem is when you do just this:

```
child.getAllNodes();
```

You are not using the response from that method...

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
names.addAll(child.getAllNodes());
```